# XLSX2CSV in pandas only reading filtered rows in excel unlike read_excel(). How to read all rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use XLSX2CSV instead of read_excel() method since XLSX2CSV is faster. But issue is it is only reading filtered rows in excel and not all the rows.
I am using XLSX2CSV because it is faster in reading excel files as compared to read_excel() from openpyxl. But using XLSX2CSV only reads filtered rows of a sheet whereas read_excel() reads all rows regardless if the sheet is filtered or not.
I havent found any method to read all rows using XLSX2CSV. Below is the sample code

```
filepath = os.path.join(FolderPath, FileName)
a = load_workbook(filepath, read_only=True)

def read_excel_file(path: str, sheet_index: int) -> pd.DataFrame:
buffer = StringIO()
     Xlsx2csv(path, outputencoding="utf8").convert(buffer,sheetid=sheet_index)
buffer.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(buffer)
return df
```

dfinal=read_excel_file(filepath,a.index(a.get_sheet_by_name('Sheetname'))+1)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to the above question?